# How do I lock map boundaries to a specific location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, drag

How do I lock the map boundaries to a specific location in Google Map API v3? So the user cannot drag to another place, while he can still zoom in and out?

To be more clear, I need my view box to show/view just my country only so the user cannot drag to other countires.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this as an option on the map object.

```
map.Options{ draggable: false};
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions